# Excel to html code does not run on mpdf

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, excel, mpdf

Following is my code:

```
    <?php
include('mPDF/mpdf.php'); 
//$mpdf = new mPDF();


$mpdf=new mPDF('c','A4','9','','10' , '18' , '50' , '50' , '50','13','P' ); 


$start="<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>CSV File to HTML Table Using AJAX jQuery</title>
  <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css' />
  <script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class='container'>
   <div class='table-responsive'>
    <h1 align='center'>CSV File to HTML Table Using AJAX jQuery</h1>
    <br />
    <div align='center'>
     <button type='button' name='load_data' id='load_data' class='btn btn-info'>Load Data</button>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id='employee_table'>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(window).on( 'load', function() {
 //$('button').load(function(){
  $.ajax({
   url:'pick.csv',
   dataType:'text',
   success:function(data)
   {
    var employee_data = data.split(/\r?\n|\r/);
    var empl_data=employee_data.length-1;

     //1st part
    var table_data = '<table border=1 >';
    for(var count = 0; count<10; count++)
    {
         console.log('employee_data'+empl_data);

     var cell_data = employee_data[count].split(',');
     table_data += '<tr>';
     for(var cell_count=0; cell_count<cell_data.length; cell_count++)
     {
         console.log('cell_data'+cell_data.length);
      if(count === 0)
      {
       table_data += '<th>'+cell_data[cell_count]+'</th>';
      }
      else
      {
       table_data += '<td>'+cell_data[cell_count]+'</td>';
      }
     }
     table_data += '</tr>';
    }
    table_data += '</table>';

    //2nd part
    var table_data1 = '<table border=1 >';
    for(var count = 10; count<20; count++)
    {
         console.log('employee_data'+empl_data);

     var cell_data = employee_data[count].split(',');
     table_data1 += '<tr>';
     for(var cell_count=0; cell_count<cell_data.length; cell_count++)
     {
         console.log('cell_data'+cell_data.length);
      if(count === 0)
      {
       table_data1 += '<th>'+cell_data[cell_count]+'</th>';
      }
      else
      {
       table_data1 += '<td>'+cell_data[cell_count]+'</td>';
      }
     }
     table_data1 += '</tr>';
    }
    table_data1 += '</table>';

    //3nd part

    var table_data2 = '<table border=1 >';
    for(var count = 20; count<empl_data; count++)
    {
         console.log('employee_data'+empl_data);

     var cell_data = employee_data[count].split(',');
     table_data2 += '<tr>';
     for(var cell_count=0; cell_count<cell_data.length; cell_count++)
     {
         console.log('cell_data'+cell_data.length);
      if(count === 0)
      {
       table_data2 += '<th>'+cell_data[cell_count]+'</th>';
      }
      else
      {
       table_data2 += '<td>'+cell_data[cell_count]+'</td>';
      }
     }
     table_data2 += '</tr>';
    }
    table_data2 += '</table>';



    $('#employee_table').html(table_data+'<br><br><br>'+table_data1+'<br><br><br>'+table_data2);
 console.log(count);
   }
  });
 });

});
</script>";

//$mpdf->SetHeader( $header);

$mpdf->SetFooter($footer.'{PAGENO}');








$mpdf->WriteHTML($start);

//echo $start;

$mpdf->Output();


?>
```

This code doesn't work, only the html part works on browser but doesn't work on mpdf.

> Error comes in the regular expression (data.split(/\r?\n|\r/);)

I want a csv file loaded on pdf.